# Is the "Dr. Strange" post credits scene the first to appear in a later movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, doctor-strange-2016

The post-credits scene in *Doctor Strange* is an excerpt from a longer scene that takes place in *Thor: Ragnarok*.

## Is this the first time in the MCU that a mid/post credits scene has literally appeared in a later film?

Comment: Cannot confirm this but I'm pretty sure that Ant-Man's [post credit scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4UF1OFAc_g) was an excerpt from Civil War.

Comment: This is the third or fourth time they've done that.

Comment: Is it a post-credits scene or would it be more proper to call it an embedded advertisement?

Comment: Huh, I'd completely forgotten about that by the time I watched Ragnarok!

Comment: I absolutely love the way the MCU holds together as a coherent whole. And now they've brought Spidey back into the fold properly. :)

Answer (score 65):

### Roughly one quarter of MCU movies have recycled end credits scenes.

- **The post credits scene from *Iron Man 2* was used in *Thor*.**
- **The post credits scene from *Captain America: The First Avenger* was used in *The Avengers*.**
- **The post credits scene from *Ant-Man* was used in *Captain America: Civil War*.**
- **The post credits scene from *Dr Strange* was used in *Thor: Ragnarok*.**

Comment: These seem to be phrased backwards.   It seems like it would be more accurate to say "A scene from later movie X was used as the post/mid-credits scene in earlier movie Y."

Answer (score 25):

No. The stinger in *Ant-Man* was later reused and expanded upon in *Captain America: Civil War*.

*Ant-Man* was released June 29, 2015, while *Doctor Strange* was released October 20, 2016.

Answer (score 9):

The [scene from *Ant-Man*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/173528/25506) was literally taken from the dailies that the Russo brothers submitted to Marvel for them for approval/oversight.

The first instance of a scene being redone like the one from Doctor Strange occurred in *Captain America: The First Avenger*. This scene was directed originally by Joe Johnston, then when the scene was used in *Avengers*, Joss Whedon recreated it.